# Python doubts about calling func and Syntax

Tags: python, function, logic

I'm totally newbie, even I'm still reading the python docs I get myself with syntax doubts.

I have my functions in my.py

```
def f1:
  pass

def f2:
  pass

def f3:
  pass
```

So I would like to choose a number to call a function like:

```
a = input('Insert the function number')
```

"f$d"() %a #I tried something like that, totally weird, but I'm newbie (a kinda stupid).

Sorry if it's a stupid question, but I don't have idea how I can make it.

Comment: Aside: Python syntax demands that even functions which take no arguments get parentheses in their definitions.  IOW, it has to be `def f1(): pass` etc.

Comment: What do you mean, "describe my functions"? Does `list_func` contains the function names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this quite easily. Make a list of your functions:

```
list_func = [f1, f2, f3]
```

And th execution:

```
a = int(input('insert the function number: ') #get the input and convert it to integer
list_func[a]() #execute the function inputted
```

Or without list_func:

```
inp = int(input('insert the function number: ') #get the input and convert it to integer
eval('f%d'%inp)
```

Keep in mind, do not use `eval()` too often. It's a bit insecure.

Alternatively, you can call it from the `globals()`, it's able to return a dictionary of the global variables and functions:

```
globals()['f%d'%inp]()
```

Nah, that's about it.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Python's functions are standard objects like ints, strings, lists etc. The canonical way to map arbitrary keys (names, numbers etc) to objects so you can lookup the objects by key is to use a `dict`. So:

```
 def func1():
     print "func1"

 def func2():
     print "func1"

 def func3():
     print "func1"


functions = {
    "key1": func1,
    "key2": func2,
    "key3": func3,
    }


while True:
    key = raw_input("type the key or 'Q' to quit:")
    if key in functions:
        # get the function
        f = functions[key]
        # and call it:
        f()
   elif key == "Q":
        break
   else:
        print "unknown key '%s'" % key
```